# Xcode C++ bug on int declaration

Tags: c++, xcode

Running the following in Xcode results in a crash.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int x = 0;
    while (x < 101){
        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A thread breakpoint occurs at the `int x = 0;` line.
The value given is x 1606422582.

I'd be happy to provide extra information, I'm new to Xcode so I'm not sure what is available.

It also crashes on:

```
int main () {
    int x = 0;
}
```

Xcode has been working fine for me quite sometime. It started to do this in mid-session.

Comment: IIRC Xcode is an IDE, not a Compiler?

Comment: This is not a minimal verifiable example -- you don't use anything from iostream, or from namespace std. You should remove those lines and try again, if that fixes the crash it gives you a big clue.

Comment: Probably your Compiler installation is messed up, and the program stalls when trying to load c++ standard shared libs.

Comment: @ChrisBeck I did what you suggested and got an error again.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `int x = 0;` then x will be random data since that assignment has not yet happened yet.  On the next line, x should be zero.  If you're experiencing a crash, please post the stack and any relevant error/exception messages.

Comment: Bren: I think πάντα ῥεῖ is right, you need to reinstall xcode command line tools, they are messed up somehow. If you want to further debug whether it is Xcode vs. the compiler, you could try compiling code from the command line. Syntax is like `g++ main.cpp -o main`, in the OS X terminal. A text file like `int main() {}` should definitely compile and not crash. If it is broken, then you know the compiler is broken, if it works then it must be xcode somehow.

Comment: if you get crash "there" with this value, then it means, that this did not execute this line. Debuggers often give such an info, that program crashed on line, that was not executed yet. In fact your program probably failed before jumping (on jumping) to main function. Problem with loading functions are very likely to be true.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or a log output, since it tells you exactly what happened. As i_am_jorf already mentioned, a random value is usual before the assignment of 0 was executed.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit strange, I have had similar issues and by separating the int and declaration statements, it usually fixes the issue.

EDIT: I did some more work, and I saw that maybe moving the variable initialization before the main function helps.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int x=0;
int main () {
while (x < 101){
    x++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No; the answer is in the comments to the question.  Putting the breakpoint on a statement will break execution *before* the statement is executed,

Comment: Wait, I dont follow? Could you explain a little?

Comment: The so-called "bug" is not a bug.  If the breakpoint is on the `int x = 0;` statement then that statement hasn't been executed yet and so `x` could contain anything.

Comment: Yes I know that. And by seperating the `x=0;` part could fix it.

Comment: There is nothing to fix.

Comment: Oh, I just got it. Thanks for clarifying.